# How do I search for a value in a file and print it using Perl?

Tags: perl, shell, unix, jmx

I am having trouble searching for a value and printing it. This is what I have so far. What am I doing wrong? How do i get the desired output by searching in the output?

```
my $host = $ARGV[0];
my $port = $ARGV[1];
my $domain = $ARGV[2];
my $bean = $ARGV[3];
my $get = $ARGV[4];

open(FILE, ">", "/home/hey");
print FILE "open $host:$port\n";
print FILE "domain $domain\n";
print FILE "bean $bean\n";
print FILE "get -s $get\n";
print FILE "close\n";
close FILE;    
open JMX, "/root/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/java -jar /var/scripts/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -v      silent -n < /home//hey |";
open (dbg, ">", "/home/donejava1");
#print JMX "help \n";

foreach ( <JMX> )
{
chomp;
print $_;
open (LOG, ">", "/home/out1");
print LOG $_;
close LOG;
}
```

//output

```
{
committed = 313733;
init = 3221225472;
max = 3137339392;
used = 1796598680;
}
```

// how do i print 1796598680, looking for the attribute "used" ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: With that code, your /home/out1 file will never have more than one line in it. Even if you move the `open` statement outside the loop.

Comment: yeah just verified, u were right

Comment: how do i get it instead of writing to the file, from the standard output by passing the required parameter(used)

Comment: @Shashank That sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Use `grep` to search in a file.

Answer (score 2):

The following example should provide a solution for you.

```
perl -lne'print $1 if /used\s*=\s*(\d+);/' filename
```

Comment: sorry, i was looking to get the output not from the file , from the output